# Upgrading to angular 9 - @angular/flex-layout peer dependency to @angular/cdk

Tags: angular, angular-material

I encountered following the error whilst updating from angular 8 to 9 and running

`ng update @angular/material`:

> Package "@angular/flex-layout" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cdk" (requires "^8.0.0-rc.0", would install "9.0.0").

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have to update both dependencies at the same time.
Had the same issue when only updating one at a time.

```
ng update @angular/material @angular/flex-layout
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

Fixed by:

```
npm uninstall @angular/flex-layout

ng update @angular/material

npm install @angular/flex-layout
```

Comment: Thanks, the update went because of your post although it was a bit tough;)